# Query does not work with ORDER BY with two `in` clause in Room Persistence lib

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am implementing filter in an app where i need to use `in` clause
 in sqlite query to fetch data but following does not work:\

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM NewsItem WHERE category in (:selectedCategories)  and publisher in (:selectedPublishers)  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET :offset")
    Single<List<NewsItem>> getFilteredAscNewsList(int offset, String[] selectedCategories, String[] selectedPublishers);
```

Snipped that uses above method:

```
newsDao.getFilteredAscNewsList(offset, selectedCategories, selectedPublishers).subscribe(subscriber);
```

---

But when i remove one of the two `in` clause or `ORDER BY` clause like following, it works with out any problem:

When I remove `ORDER BY` clause like following, query works.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM NewsItem WHERE category in (:selectedCategories)  and publisher in (:selectedPublishers)")
    Single<List<NewsItem>> getFilteredAscNewsList(/*int offset, */String[] selectedCategories, String[] selectedPublishers);
```

Snipped that uses above method:

```
newsDao.getFilteredAscNewsList(/*offset, */selectedCategories, selectedPublishers).subscribe(subscriber);
```

---

When i remove one of two `in` clause but keep `ORDER BY` clause, it still works.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM NewsItem WHERE category in (:selectedCategories)  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET :offset")
    Single<List<NewsItem>> getFilteredAscNewsList(int offset, String[] selectedCategories/*, String[] selectedPublishers*/);
```

Snipped that uses above method:

```
newsDao.getFilteredAscNewsList(offset, selectedCategories/*, selectedPublishers*/).subscribe(subscriber);
```

Am i missing something here or there is a bug in Room lib.

I have checked it with version `1.0.0-alpha9` and `1.0.0-alpha9-1`, both don't work.

does Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are binding both parameters?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah, i can show but to just let you know, i have debugged the auto generated code by room, there it self cursor does not contain any data.

Comment: I completely trust your observations, but you should show us the relevant code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen refresh it just edited.

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen did you check?

Comment: I don't know this framework well enough to answer.  Maybe someone else can help you +1 nevertheless.

Comment: I don't know this framework well enough to answer.  Maybe someone else can help you +1 nevertheless.

Comment: What is the size of the arrays?

Comment: @CL. between 1 - 5.

Comment: You are not sendind selectedPublishers in your first call, getFilteredAscNewsList(String[] selectedCategories); Is that deliberate?

Comment: Also, please explain in detail what "does not work" means. I would expect a compile error due to the problem that Debanjan pointed out.

Comment: @Debanjan really sorry, there were some typos and  question was not well explained. I was in hurry as there was an on going hackathon. Now i have added relevant codes snippets with explanation. Please check.

Comment: @CommonsWare really sorry, there were some typos and question was not well explained. I was in hurry as there was an on going hackathon. Now i have added relevant codes snippets with explanation. Please check.

Comment: @chandil03: Please explain **in detail** what "does not work" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare No result is returned from query. There is no error no logs nothing. I debugged the generated room code, debugger reaches to check `cursor.moveToFirst()` method and that returns false. And empty list of `NewsItem` is returned.

Comment: My guess is that this is a Room limitation, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Since on the first query, there are three params, try moving the param int offset to the end. Although I guess Room handles this, but to be sure, just check it once.

Comment: @Debanjan i have tried removing offset also, no luck.